# Angular 4 Karma component test fail due to CORS issue

Tags: angular

when I run `ng test` I get this error (I use standard setup with `Karma`) when I try to test component:

`XMLHttpRequest cannot load ng:///DynamicTestModule/FullModalHeaderComponent.ngfactory.js. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.`

How can I address this issue?

Code:

```
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';

import { FullModalHeaderComponent } from './full-modal-header.component';

describe('FullModalHeaderComponent', () => {
  let component: FullModalHeaderComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<FullModalHeaderComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [FullModalHeaderComponent]
    })
      .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(FullModalHeaderComponent);
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should be created', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

and

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { ProcessingCenter, Publication } from '../../publications/model';

@Component({
  selector: 'gom-full-modal-header',
  templateUrl: './full-modal-header.component.html'
})
export class FullModalHeaderComponent {

  @Input('processingCenter') processingCenter: ProcessingCenter;
  @Input('publication') publication: Publication;
  @Input('title') title: string;

}
```

Also, when I run tests with `ng test --sourcemaps=false` issue goes away.

Comment: Can you post your test code ? This is most probably coming from here

Comment: Sure, test code is generated from angular-cli

Comment: Can you try running `ng test --sourcemaps=false` and update the post ? This issue is most probably a fake one since there is no way this is a CORS issue. Also, can you post your HTML template code ? I think this is coming from here

Comment: Wow! Now it works.

Comment: Be sure to check for your template variables, the issue was coming from here. Most likely an input value not being instanciated when the test is running or something like that. Adding the safe navigation operator might just solve all the issues and you might not even need `--sourcemaps=false` anymore.  exemple : `{{entity.count}}` ==> `{{entity?.count}}`

Comment: also look into that : https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/7296

Answer (score 18):

This can also happen if you have something like this:

- Your `constructor` or `onInit` calls a service
- That service is faked/mocked so that it returns a result
- The subscription on your service sets a property on your component
- **The component html has an error**, for example:

```html
    <strong>{{ result.item.subproperty }}</strong>
    <!--             ^^^^^^                    -->
    <!--      ^ could be null in tests ^       -->
```

Note that if `item` is `undefined` because your fake/mock didn't have it, the component template will cause an exception, indirectly causing this problem.

So check your html for this type of problem, and fix your fake/mock and/or make your template more robust.

Comment: This is a complete answer. In addition I had a TypeError for the same test complaining about no next being defined, perhaps because it was trying to iterate a field that did not exist.

Comment: This answer is really helpful. I had an error in the nested child component.

Answer (score 14):

Component tests can fail with this error when there is an uninitialised `@Input`.

Provide sensible defaults for all your `@Input` properties:

```
@Input('processingCenter') processingCenter: ProcessingCenter = null;
@Input('publication') publication: Publication = null;
@Input('title') title: string = '';
```

Or make sure to initialise them in your tests:

```
it('should be created', () => {
  component.processingCenter = new ProcessingCenter();
  component.publication = new Publication();
  component.title = 'The Title';
  expect(component).toBeTruthy();
});
```

Comment: This didn't fix my issue but it is the correct reason for my issue. However, my situation is different from above. I think this should work for the current question.

Answer (score 2):

This happened to me as well. For anyone who arrives here via Google, if you have ejected your Angular project out of the CLI, I resolved this by editing the angular-cli.json and marking ejected false.

After that, I was able to run the suggestion above and find out my real error message.

For me, it was a piece of my component template that was making use of an injected service that was undefined in my unit test.

Answer (score 1):

I stumbled on this issue too. Here are the things to look for (Just consolidating all possibilities into one location). I resolved my issue using first and second steps

1. Try ng test --source-map=false to see if there's an issue elsewhere.
2. If the issue is resolved by simply adding --source-map=false and if you are using mock services that returns an observable, make sure subscribers have an error handler, then you do not need the source-map false flag

   this.fe.getData().subscribe(d => {
   ...
   }, err => console.log(err));
3. Use safe navigators in your HTML
4. Make sure component inputs are set in test env check @tanya's answer

Answer (score -1):

It's caused by failed case(s). The real problem we want to address, is to fix the error, not hide it.

Try to use my solution [Solution to fix your Angular 5 – TestBed bug of XMLHttpRequest cannot load ng:///DynamicTestModule/-](https://www.xiaofang.me/2019/03/07/solution-to-fix-your-angular-5-testbed-bug-of-xmlhttprequest-cannot-load-ng-dynamictestmodule-%E4%BF%AE%E5%A4%8D-angular-5-testbed-%E4%BB%A5%E8%B0%83%E8%AF%95%E6%B5%8B%E8%AF%95%E7%94%A8/)

With my fix, there is no need to disable `sourcemap` and the real debugging info is revealed.

Comment: Not sure why my answer was down-voted. I use it very smoothly and it releases me from the greate hassling.

Comment: Probably because it involves modifying library files.